# Doctrine query not returning the same result depending on the order of the join

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I want to do one query, and I thought I could write it in the following two ways:

```
SELECT c, p
FROM MyBundle:Car c
    JOIN c.person p
WHERE
    p.name =  :name
```

and

```
SELECT c, p
FROM MyBundle:Person p
    JOIN p.car c
WHERE
    p.name =  :name
```

Since in both cases I was asking for "c, p" in that particular order, I was expecting the query to return the same thing, however, in the first case the object I get is of the type Car and on the second case is of type Person.

I don't understand why this happens, any light would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first one says: give me every car attached to a person,  where person's name is :name.  Naturally this is a list of cars.

The second says give me every person attached to a car, where person's name is :name.  Naturally this is a list of persons.

Since they are joined, doctrine eager loads the related entity as a field of the primary select, which is indicated by the from clause.

Basically, this is object oriented view, this is how dql works.  Your contention that they should be the same is a tuple-oriented view, which is how sql works.  Mastering this concept is essential for effective use of doctrine.